# SQL Monthname Display in Query

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and currently going through some training materials.

I need to: Display the month and number of quotations received in each month.

[image: Output Expected]

---

My Query

```
SELECT Qdate AS MONTH ,COUNT (Quotationid)AS QUOTATIONCOUNT
FROM Quotation
GROUP BY Qdate
ORDER BY Qdate ASC;
```

DB Structure

- Quotation (Quotationid, Sname, Itemcode, Quotedprice, Qdate, Qstatus)

Comment: Most people where want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct.

Below query for Oracle.

```
SELECT to_char(Qdate, 'MONTH') AS "MONTH" ,COUNT (Quotationid)AS QUOTATIONCOUNT
FROM Quotation
GROUP BY to_char(Qdate, 'MONTH')
ORDER BY "MONTH";
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

And to show month name:

- in SQL Server, you can use `DATENAME` function in combination with `DATEADD` function. `@MonthNum` is your number of month, that means you can use: 
  **`SELECT DateName(month, DateAdd(month, @MonthNum, 0) - 1)`**
- in MySQL, you can use:
   **`MONTHNAME(date)`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the month and year to get what you want.  Date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.  In standard SQL you can do:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Qdate) AS YYYY, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Qdate) AS MM, 
       COUNT(*) AS QUOTATIONCOUNT
FROM Quotation
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Qdate), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Qdate)
ORDER BY MIN(Qdate) ASC;
```

The specific functions you want depend on the database you are using.

Important points:

- You should not be considering the month without the year, unless you have a really good reason.
- In general, you need to repeat the expressions in the `GROUP BY`, although some databases do allow column aliases (such as `GROUP BY YYYY, MM` in the above example).
- The `ORDER BY` needs to use an expression that only consists of expressions in the `GROUP BY` or aggregation functions (so `ORDER BY QDate` wouldn't work).